# How to create Hash:ActiveSupport in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have an object that I converted to YAML but it's not giving me the same result which I want.

The result I got

```
---
accepted:
  first_order_date:
    consition: between_date
    value: 2021-11-28 00:00:00&2021-11-22 00:00:00
removed: {}
```

The result I want

```
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
accepted: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  number_of_order: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    condition: between_number
    value: 0&5
removed: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess {}
```

And here is my code

```
require 'yaml'
require 'json'

yaml_str = '{"accepted":{"first_order_date":{"consition":"between_date","value":"2021-11-28 00:00:00&2021-11-22 00:00:00"}},"removed":{}}'

puts JSON.parse(yaml_str).to_yaml
```

I'm new at ruby so please help to find out how can i do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want result with `HashWithIndifferentAccess` You can do this before `to_yaml`

```
require 'yaml'
require 'json'

yaml_str = '{"accepted":{"first_order_date":{"consition":"between_date","value":"2021-11-28 00:00:00&2021-11-22 00:00:00"}},"removed":{}}'

parsed_output = JSON.parse(yaml_str)
yaml_output   = parsed_output.with_indifferent_access.to_yaml
puts yaml_output
```

Output:

```
puts JSON.parse(yaml_str).with_indifferent_access.to_yaml
--- !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
accepted: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
  first_order_date: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess
    consition: between_date
    value: 2021-11-28 00:00:00&2021-11-22 00:00:00
removed: !ruby/hash:ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess {}
 => nil
```

Ref: [hash_with_indifferent_access offcial](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html)